# Is it possible to receive no pay because all the money goes to union fees?

Tags: canada, labor-law, british-columbia, unions

A bit of a follow up to [Union fees were deducted but was never told there was a union](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79019/union-fees-were-deducted-but-was-never-told-there-was-a-union)

If someone works for an employer for a very short time (for example 1 or 2 hours) is it possible to receive a net of no pay because of the various deductions such as union fees? Is it possible to have worked and actually owe money because the time was so short it didn't cover all the union fees? (Though I am tagging this question Canada, I am curious what other countries have)

Comment: I suspect that it is such a low stakes edge case that it has not been litigated in a way that generates binding case law and that there is no statute or regulation directly on point.

Comment: In practice, union dues are almost always a percentage of the gross income and/or a small amount per hour (perhaps with a monthly cap).